# Haskell - functions as an input to a function

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I am looking at this code for a small step WHILE interpreter, and I am trying to understand how to run it. Specifically, I am confused about the State type. It seems to be a type of function - Does that mean that a function that is of type State = Var->Val has to be defined somewhere, and that function needs to be passed to the functions that require it?

At the same time, I see that the state should be modifiable by variable assignments. How does the upd function work, if it is only passed in a function that is of type Var->Val?

Thanks for your help! I can't seem to find anything about this on the tutorials or on stackoverflow.

```
type Var = Integer
type Val = Integer
type State = Var -> Val


--takes a var, returns a val. Here, we use an integer to describe a
-- variable as opposed to a string.
lkp :: Var -> State -> Val
lkp x s = s x

upd :: Var -> Val -> State -> State
upd x v s = \y -> if x == y then v else s y

data AExp = N Integer | V Var
            | AExp :+ AExp | AExp :- AExp | AExp :* AExp
   deriving (Show)

aexp :: AExp -> State -> Integer
aexp (N z) _ = z
aexp (V x) s = lkp x s
aexp (a0 :+ a1) s = aexp a0 s + aexp a1 s
aexp (a0 :- a1) s = aexp a0 s - aexp a1 s
aexp (a0 :* a1) s = aexp a0 s * aexp a1 s

data BExp = TT | FF | AExp :== AExp | AExp :<= AExp
            | Not BExp | BExp :&& BExp | BExp :|| BExp
   deriving (Show)

bexp :: BExp -> State -> Bool
bexp TT _ = True
bexp FF _ = False
bexp (a0 :== a1) s = aexp a0 s == aexp a1 s
bexp (a0 :<= a1) s = aexp a0 s <= aexp a1 s
bexp (Not b) s = not (bexp b s)
bexp (a0 :&& a1) s = bexp a0 s && bexp a1 s
bexp (a0 :|| a1) s = bexp a0 s || bexp a1 s

data Stmt = Skip | Stmt :\ Stmt | Var := AExp
            | If BExp Stmt Stmt | While BExp Stmt

data Trace = Nil State | Delay State Trace

--reduces the statement by one step.
red :: Stmt -> State -> Maybe (Stmt, State)
red Skip s = Nothing
red (x := a) s = Just (Skip, upd x v s) where v = aexp a s
red (stmt0 :\ stmt1) s =
    case red stmt0 s of
        Just (stmt0', s') -> Just (stmt0' :\ stmt1, s')
        Nothing -> red stmt1 s
red (If b stmt0 stmt1) s =
    if bexp b s then
        Just (stmt0, s)
    else Just (stmt1, s)
red (While b stmt0) s =
    if bexp b s then
        Just (stmt0 :\ While b stmt0, s)
    else Just (Skip, s)

norm :: Stmt -> State -> Trace
norm stmt s =
    case red stmt s of
        Nothing -> Nil s
        Just (stmt', s') -> Delay s (norm stmt' s')
```

Comment: @9000 This is not the standard `State`, this is `type State = Var -> Val`.

Comment: "*Does that mean that a function that is of type State = Var->Val has to be defined somewhere*" - All functions you use have to be defined somewhere regardless of their type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can think of the `State` type as an environment where you can look up variables. You can start with an "empty" environment like so:

```
emptyState v = error ("variable " ++ show v ++ " is unknown")
```

As far as I can see, the environment is updated every time the interpreter sees a

```
var := value
```

construct. That is, after

```
V 23 := 42
```

the state function that is used in subsequent statements will look like:

```
state1 v = if v == 23 then 42 else emptyState v
```

Interestingly, the set up of the `emptyState` function determines important semantic properties of the interpreted language. The `emptyState` above, for example, forbids undefined variables. But it would be as well possible to come up with a variant that treats all undefined variables as 0, or 1, or 42.

Comment: Your answer is much better (and more concise) than mine! It might be worth showing what `state2` might look like

Comment: @AdamSmith well, we shouldn't underestimate the imagination of the OP :) What is more interesting is that we could also have a "undefined variables don't exist, they're just 0" semantics.